# Java Datanucleus is it possible to use the sql in operator with JDOQL

Tags: java, sql, datanucleus, jdoql

I am new to datanucleus.

Is it possible to use the Sql in operater ind JDOQL in datanucleus?

I want to use [declerative JDOQL](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/jdoql.html) but I cannot figure out how to create a query that does what the [SQL In Operater](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) does.

SQL Query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Thanks for helpful information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would JDOQL allow some random bit of SQL? JDOQL uses **Java syntax**, consequently the most logical Java syntax is *Collection.contains* so you pass in a Collection parameter which has those 5 elements, and do

```
:param.contains(id)
```

Obviously looking at the JDO spec would tell you that, and DataNucleus does nothing different.

Comment: Yeah just came to the same solution :-) works fine. I was looking for the JDOQL way to do it.